# How to convert generic exception into BAPIRET2 message?

Tags: exception, abap

I have several custom exception classes that were created "With Message Class". Since I can't directly get a message from them, I want to create a utility method that returns a `BAPIRET2` from a given exception based on the values in `IF_T100_MESSAGE~T100KEY`. However, I can't provide that method with a generic `CX_ROOT` importing parameter as this class is not message-enabled. I also can't create a generic message-enabled exception class as new classes have to inherit from one of `CX_STATIC_CHECK`, `CX_DYNAMIC_CHECK`, or `CX_NOCHECK`.

How can I then retrieve the message details from an unspecified exception? Should I create a method that receives a `CX_ROOT` and then does up to three calls to methods with an import typed to each of the three possible subclasses? Or are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prepare a type descriptor of the interface (once):

```
DATA: lr_t100_descr TYPE REF TO cl_abap_intfdescr.

lr_t100_descr ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( 'IF_T100_MESSAGE' ).
```

and then examine each exception as it comes your way:

```
DATA: lr_t100_exception TYPE REF TO if_t100_message.

IF lr_t100_descr->applies_to( ir_any_exception ) = abap_true.
  lr_t100_exception ?= ir_any_exception.
  " ...
ENDIF.
```

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for. Accepted with the caveat that I didn't test it in my scenario as its spec changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the message collector object, so for example

```
DATA:
  excp              type ref to CX_ROOT,
  bapi_messages     type BAPIRETTAB,
  message_collector type ref to IF_RECA_MESSAGE_LIST.

FIELD_SYMBOLS:
  <bapi_message>    TYPE BAPIRET2.

message_collector = cf_reca_message_list=>create( ).

TRY.
 " some code which may cause and exception
CATCH cx_root into excp.
  message_collector->add_from_exxeption( io_exception = excp).
ENDTRY.

bapi_messages = message_collector->get_list_as_bapiret( ).

LOOP AT bapi_messages ASSIGNING <bapi_message>.
  " write out message
ENDLOOP.
```

It is well worth checking out the message collector object.

For example
http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/profile/2007/07/09/Message+Handling+-+Finding+the+Needle+in+the+Haystack

Answer (score 1):

For a logging class I use something like this:

```
METHOD add_message_exception.
  DATA:
    lr_type         TYPE REF TO cl_abap_typedescr,
    lr_class        TYPE REF TO cl_abap_classdescr,
    lr_intf         TYPE REF TO cl_abap_intfdescr,
    l_bapiret2      TYPE bapiret2,
    lr_msg          TYPE REF TO if_t100_message.

  CHECK ir_exception IS NOT INITIAL.

  l_bapiret2-type       = i_type.

  "Test for T100KEY interface
  cl_abap_classdescr=>describe_by_object_ref(
    EXPORTING
      p_object_ref         = ir_exception
    RECEIVING
      p_descr_ref          = lr_type
   EXCEPTIONS
      reference_is_initial = 1
      OTHERS               = 2  ).
  TRY.
      lr_class ?= lr_type.
      IF sy-subrc = 0.
        lr_class->get_interface_type(
          EXPORTING
            p_name              = 'IF_T100_MESSAGE'
          RECEIVING
            p_descr_ref         = lr_intf
          EXCEPTIONS
            interface_not_found = 1
            OTHERS              = 2 ).
        IF sy-subrc = 0.
          lr_msg ?= ir_exception.  "Cast to interface
          l_bapiret2-id         = lr_msg->t100key-msgid.
          l_bapiret2-number     = lr_msg->t100key-msgno.

          cl_message_helper=>set_msg_vars_for_if_t100_msg( text = lr_msg ).

          l_bapiret2-message_v1 = sy-msgv1.
          l_bapiret2-message_v2 = sy-msgv2.
          l_bapiret2-message_v3 = sy-msgv3.
          l_bapiret2-message_v4 = sy-msgv4.

          l_bapiret2-message = me->get_msg(
              i_msgid = l_bapiret2-id
              i_msgno = l_bapiret2-number ).
        ENDIF.
      ENDIF.
    CATCH cx_root.
      "Pokémon exception handling
  ENDTRY.

  "No T100KEY Interface available
  IF lr_msg IS INITIAL.
    l_bapiret2-message    = ir_exception->if_message~get_text( ).
    l_bapiret2-message_v1 = sy-msgv1.
    l_bapiret2-message_v2 = sy-msgv2.
    l_bapiret2-message_v3 = sy-msgv3.
    l_bapiret2-message_v4 = sy-msgv4.
  ENDIF.
ENDMETHOD.
```

Hope this helps as I struggled with the same problem. Maybe there is some adjustment needed, but I think you get the basic idea. This method can handle

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but can't you just use `IF_MESSAGE~GET_TEXT` which is present on `CX_ROOT` ?

Otherwise, I would make it the responsibility of the custom exception class to have a method that can return a proper message ( it might rely on the utility method you are planning on ).

Comment: I tried that approach but IIRC the text returned by that method doesn't even match the T100 message set in a message-enabled class. Even if it did, it would only get me the text, not the message (class) ID and number that I'd need. You do make a good point in suggesting that the utility method I have in mind be defined on the exception class itself. One solution would be to create message-enabled implementations of the three base exception types with that utility method and derive my custom exceptions from those classes.